# How to group data.table by multiple columns?

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I'm using the `data.table` package to speed up some summary statistic collection on a data set.

I'm curious if there's a way to group by more than one column.  My data looks like this:

```
  purchaseAmt        adShown        url
   15.54            00001         150000001
    4.82            00002         150000001
  157.99            05005         776300044
   ...               ...            ...
```

I can do something like this:

```
adShownMedian <- df1[,median(purchaseAmt),by="adShown"]
```

to get each ad's median.  How would I do something that combines `adShown` and `url`?

I've tried this:

```
adShownMedian <- df1[,median(purchaseAmt),by=c("adShown","url")]
```

but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of `data.table` are you using? I'm fairly certain version 1.8.2 allows you to pass a character vector of column names to the `by` argument.

Comment: Exactly. Either a (very) old version of data.table, or there was some other error.  `?data.table` says: "`by` - A single unquoted column name, a list() of expressions of column names, a single character string containing comma separated column names, or a character vector of column names."   So `c("adShown","url")` should be fine, or `"adShown,url"`, or `list(adShown,url)`.

Comment: @BenBarnes: Good catch, I'm still back on 1.8.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use `by=list(adShown,url)` instead of `by=c("adShown","url")`

Example:

```
set.seed(007) 
DF <- data.frame(X=1:20, Y=sample(c(0,1), 20, TRUE), Z=sample(0:5, 20, TRUE))

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, Mean:=mean(X), by=list(Y, Z)]


     X Y Z      Mean
 1:  1 1 3  1.000000
 2:  2 0 1  9.333333
 3:  3 0 5  7.400000
 4:  4 0 5  7.400000
 5:  5 0 5  7.400000
 6:  6 1 0  6.000000
 7:  7 0 3  7.000000
 8:  8 1 2 12.500000
 9:  9 0 5  7.400000
10: 10 0 2 15.000000
11: 11 0 4 14.500000
12: 12 0 1  9.333333
13: 13 1 1 13.000000
14: 14 0 1  9.333333
15: 15 0 2 15.000000
16: 16 0 5  7.400000
17: 17 1 2 12.500000
18: 18 0 4 14.500000
19: 19 1 5 19.000000
20: 20 0 2 15.000000
```

Comment: But `by=c("adShown","url")` should be fine, too. +1 anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to just show the aggregated `Y`, `Z` and `Mean` columns, just as `aggregate` works?

Comment: as far as I can tell, with ``list`` you don't need to quote the names as you do with vectors ``c()``, which is kind of interesting.

Comment: So when you are grouping by Y and Z, it should appear only once in DT. For instance, you should have only one row when Y=0, Z=5 and Mean=7.40. However, you have five of those in your DT. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PatrickT Thanks for the tip!  With this trick, you can also group by expression, which is quite handy.

Comment: @MuhsinZahidUgur If you just have `mean(X)` then you're right, but with `Mean:=mean(X)` you're assigning the grouped result to a new column. So, it's always 7.40, but the value is now copied to all the relevant rows.

Comment: Also by=.(adShown,url)

Comment: what if I want to aggregate based on columns contained in a character array?

In this case, it would be 

`mycols = c('adShown', 'url')`

It seem not to work

Comment: What if you didn't want to hardcode the columns, and instead they were from a vector x=c('adShown', 'url'), how would we be able to groupby the names in x?

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor DT[, Mean:=mean(X), x]

Answer (score 8):

To add on Jilber Urbina answer, and address kahlo comment:
if you want to get a single row for each Y - Z combination with the aggregated values you can do

```
DT[, .(X=mean(X)), by=list(Y, Z)]
```

that is the same as doing

```
DT[, .(X=mean(X)), by=.(Y, Z)] 
# or
DT[, .(X=mean(X)), by=c('Y','Z')]
# or specify column names in vector
names = c('Y','Z')
DT[, .(X=mean(X)), by=names]
```

(data.table version 1.12.6)