# r - data.table - Group data.table result by multiple columns with rounding

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I asked a previous question ([r - data.table - Why is the data.table result 1 numeric value when it should be rounded to 3 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517839/r-data-table-why-is-the-data-table-result-1-numeric-value-when-it-should-be)) about `data.table` and the displaying of a numeric result. The comments suggest that I just use `by = cyl`, but that won't give me the `dplyr` result. Thus, I'm asking a new question here.

How can I obtain the same result (see the `dplyr` code below) with `data.table`?

```
# using dplyr
mtcars1 %>%
group_by(cyl) %>%
select(disp) %>%
mutate(displace = round(disp / sum(disp), digits = 3))

# Adding missing grouping variables: `cyl`
# Source: local data frame [32 x 3]
# Groups: cyl [3]
# 
#      cyl  disp displace
#    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1      4 108.0    0.093
# 2      4 146.7    0.127
# 3      4 140.8    0.122
# 4      4  78.7    0.068
# 5      4  75.7    0.065
# 6      4  71.1    0.061
# 7      4 120.1    0.104
# 8      4  79.0    0.068
# 9      4 120.3    0.104
# 10     4  95.1    0.082
# # ... with 22 more rows
```

I have tried this (see the previous post mentioned above):

```
# Group cars by number of cylinders and the computed share of displacement
# using data.table
setkey(mtcars2, "cyl")
mtcars2[ , .(displace = round(disp / sum(disp), digits = 3)), by = list(cyl, disp)]

#    cyl  disp displace
#  1:   4 108.0        1
#  2:   4 146.7        1
#  3:   4 140.8        1
#  4:   4  78.7        1
#  5:   4  75.7        1
#  6:   4  71.1        1
#  7:   4 120.1        1
#  8:   4  79.0        1
#  9:   4 120.3        1
# 10:   4  95.1        1
#     cyl  disp displace
```

This doesn't work here (although it's worked: [How to group data.table by multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478943/how-to-group-data-table-by-multiple-columns))

```
mtcars2[ , displace = round(disp / sum(disp), digits = 3), by = list(cyl, disp)]

# Error in `[.data.table`(mtcars2, , displace = round(disp/sum(disp), digits = 3),  : 
#  unused argument (displace = round(disp/sum(disp), digits = 3))
```

This doesn't provide all of the columns that I want (as suggested in [r - data.table - Why is the data.table result 1 numeric value when it should be rounded to 3 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517839/r-data-table-why-is-the-data-table-result-1-numeric-value-when-it-should-be)):

```
mtcars2[ , .(displace = round(disp / sum(disp), digits = 3)), by = cyl]
```

Thank you.

Comment: `mtcars2[,.(displace = round(disp / sum(disp), digits = 3),disp), by = cyl]` You can wrap column `disp` in the list at `j` position if you want to keep it in the result.

Comment: @Psidom  Can you make the comment an answer? Thank you. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `summary` syntax in `data.table`, i.e, not using `:=`, you can include columns in your result by adding the column in the list at the position `j`:

```
mtcars2[,.(displace = round(disp / sum(disp), digits = 3), disp), by = cyl]

#    cyl displace  disp
# 1:   6    0.125 160.0
# 2:   6    0.125 160.0
# 3:   6    0.201 258.0
# 4:   6    0.175 225.0
# 5:   6    0.131 167.6
# 6:   6    0.131 167.6
# 7:   6    0.113 145.0
# ...
```

Comment: @Psidom, thank you for your explanation along with the answer. It works.

Comment: @thelatemail  Thank you for your suggestion, but I like the answer before in my case.