# How to group data.table by several columns consecutively

Tags: r, data.table

I want to take a bunch of descriptive statistics grouped by several hundred grouping vars.  I know from [How to group data.table by multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478943/how-to-group-data-table-by-multiple-columns) that I can use list( ) in the grouping parameter if I want the stat for a combination of grouping vars.  In my case I want the mean for each level of Y than the mean for each level of Z

```
    # example data
    set.seed(007) 
    DF <- data.frame(X=1:50000, Y=sample(c(0,1), 50000, TRUE), Z=sample(0:5, 50000, TRUE))

    library(data.table)
    DT <- data.table(DF)

    # I tried this - but this gives the mean for each combination of Y and Z
    DT[, mean(X), by=list(Y, Z)]

    # so does this
    DT[, mean(X), by=c("Y", "Z")]

    # This works but.... 
    out <- lapply( c( "Y","Z") , FUN= function(K){ DT[, mean(X), by=get(K)]})
    out <- do.call( rbind, out )
   #...but it is really slow.
```

I have 100 million records and 400+ grouping vars so need something - somewhat efficient.  The lapply option adds up to several days of extra processing time

```
options( digits=15 )
start.time <- Sys.time()
out <- lapply( c( "Y","Z") , FUN= function(K){ DT[, mean(X), by=get(K)]})
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time

start.time <- Sys.time()
DT[, mean(X), by=c("Y")]
DT[, mean(X), by=c("Z")]
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken2 <- end.time - start.time
time.taken - time.taken2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With development version 1.10.5, `data.table` has gained *Grouping Set aggregation functions* which calculate aggregates at various levels of groupings producing multiple (sub-)totals.

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.10.5 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2018-01-31 02:23:45 UTC

grp_vars <- setdiff(names(DF), "X")
groupingsets(setDT(DF), mean(X), by = grp_vars, sets = as.list(grp_vars))
```

> ```
>     Y  Z       V1
> 1:  1 NA 24960.98
> 2:  0 NA 25039.96
> 3: NA  5 24652.44
> 4: NA  0 25006.61
> 5: NA  2 25223.83
> 6: NA  3 24959.26
> 7: NA  1 25095.58
> 8: NA  4 25068.84
> ```

#### Benchmark

> ```
> # create data
> n_rows = 1e6L
> n_vars = 5
> n_grps = 1e2L
> set.seed(007) 
> DT <- data.table(rn = seq_len(n_rows))
> for (i in seq_len(n_vars)) set(DT, , paste0("X", i), i*rnorm(n_rows))
> for (i in seq_len(n_grps)) set(DT, , paste0("Z", i), sample(0:i, n_rows, TRUE))
>
> grps <- grep("^Z", names(DT), value = TRUE)
> vars <- grep("^X", names(DT), value = TRUE)
>
> # run benchmark
> bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
>   gs = {
>     groupingsets(DT, lapply(.SD, mean), by = grps, sets = as.list(grps), .SDcols = vars)
>   },
>   lapply1 = {
>     rbindlist(lapply(grps, function(K) DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = K, .SDcols = vars]), 
>                 fill = TRUE)
>   },
>   lapply2 = {
>     out <- lapply(grps, function(K) DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = get(K), .SDcols = vars])
>     do.call(rbind, out)
>   },
>   times = 3L
> )
> print(bm)
> ```

Even with 1 M rows and 100 grouping vars, there is *no* remarkable difference in the run times (`groupingsets()` seems to be a little slower than the two other approaches):

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>       gs 3.602689 3.606646 3.608343 3.610603 3.611169 3.611735     3
>  lapply1 3.524957 3.546060 3.561130 3.567163 3.579217 3.591270     3
>  lapply2 3.562424 3.569284 3.577199 3.576144 3.584586 3.593027     3
> ```

Comment: this is helpful - I get the same thing with my larger function -  lapply and the grouping sets appear to be almost the same