# Conditional combination of rows in one table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table with alternating TRUE/FALSE in variable a, like

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
b = c(20,2,1,3,2,15,1,20, 5, 10, 33, 50, 1, 20),
c = c(1,21,23,61,80,90,100,110,150,160,180,190,200,1000),
d = c(1,21,23,61,80,90,100,110,150,160,180,190,200,1000))
```

I would like to start from rows with `a==TRUE & b>=10` and combine them with all rows with `a==TRUE & b>=4` if they are only seperated by `a==FALSE & b<=2` rows (so the order of the table matters!). The newly combined rows should have

- `a==TRUE, b==sum(all combined rows$b)`,
- `c == min(all combined rows$c)`,
- `d == max(all combined rows$d)` and
- `e == (count of combinations)`.

Rows not combined with anything should be kept. So there are two "sets" of rows getting combined:

1. rows 6 to 8
2. rows 13 to 14

The problem is that I cannot use the usual summary statistics as the grouping rules are connected to the order and whether two rows are neighboring or not. Until now I was doing that with simple for-loop logic but I wonder if there is a better (and faster) way e.g. with `data.table`.
Here what I tryed: It works but I am looking for a better way with less for loops, if someone has an idea:

```
ignore_missing_scans <- function(dt){
  dt[,idx := seq(1:nrow(dt))]
  dt[,e := rep(0,nrow(dt))]


dt_p <- dt[a==TRUE & b > 10]


for(i in 1:nrow(dt_p)){

  idx.m <- dt_p[i]$idx
  dt[,idx2 := seq(1:nrow(dt))]

  up <- 0
  down <- 0

  if(nrow(dt[idx == idx.m]) == 1){

  for(x in dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2:3){
    if(x<3){break}
    if(dt[x-1]$a == FALSE & dt[x-1]$b > 2 | dt[x-2]$a == TRUE & dt[x-2]$b < 4){break}
    if(dt[x]$a == TRUE) {down <- down + 2}

  }

  for(y in dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2:nrow(dt)-2){

    if(y>nrow(dt)-2){break}
    if(dt[y+1]$a == FALSE & dt[y+1]$b > 2 | dt[y+2]$a == TRUE & dt[y+2]$b < 4){break}
    if(dt[y]$a == TRUE){up <- up + 2}
  }


  if(up>0 | down>0){
    dt[idx == idx.m]$b <- sum(dt[between(idx2,dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2-down, dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2+up)]$b)
    dt[idx == idx.m]$c <- min(dt[between(idx2,dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2-down, dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2+up)]$c)
    dt[idx == idx.m]$d <- max(dt[between(idx2,dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2-down, dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2+up)]$d)
    dt[idx == idx.m]$e <- (up + down)/2
  }

  if(down > 0){ dt <- dt[!between(idx2, dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2 - down, dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2 - 1)]}
  if(up > 0){ dt <- dt[!between(idx2, dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2 + 1, dt[idx==idx.m]$idx2 + up)]}
  }}

return(dt[,!c("idx", "idx2")])
}
```

The output for this example should be:

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
b = c(20, 2, 1, 3, 2, 51, 33, 71),
c = c(1, 21, 23, 61, 80, 90, 180, 190),
d = c(1, 21, 23, 61, 80, 160, 180, 1000),
e = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2))
```

Comment: I cannot follow your grouping logic, but would start by reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478943/how-to-group-data-table-by-multiple-columns

Comment: I think they had a quite different problem there. I edited the question and hope I explained it better now

Comment: "if they are neighboring each other" what's "they" here? The rows matching the first condition? second condition? should the 1st condition rows be neighboring the 2nd condition rows? If you've got a working `for` loop version, please include that, it would clarify what you're asking

Comment: I added my for loop approach. Hope this makes it more clear. Thank you for your patience! (sorry still quite new to coding,.. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution.

```
dt[, ID := .I]

dt[((a == T & b >= 4) | (a == F & b <= 2))
   , `:=`(a = ifelse(.N > 1, TRUE, a)
       , b = sum(b)
       , c = min(c)
       , d = max(d)
       , e = .N
       , agg_ID = unlist(.GRP)
       )
   ,by = rleid(cumsum(c(0,diff(ID) - 1)))]

dt[e == 1 | is.na(e), e:= 0]
dt[is.na(agg_ID), agg_ID := .I + max(dt[['agg_ID']], na.rm = T) ]

dt[, .SD[1], by = agg_ID]
# or 
dt[dt[, .I[1], by = agg_ID]$V1]

   agg_ID     a  b   c    d ID e
1:      4 FALSE 20   1    1  1 0
2:      5  TRUE  2  21   21  2 0
3:      1 FALSE  1  23   23  3 0
4:      6  TRUE  3  61   61  4 0
5:      2  TRUE 50  80  160  5 6
6:      7 FALSE 33 180  180 11 0
7:      3  TRUE 71 190 1000 12 3
```

The biggest leap is the `rleid(cumsum(c(0,diff(ID)-1)))`. This provides unique IDs for each group that matches your conditions. The only downside is that the third row matches the criteria but doesn't have any neighbors:

```
> dt[, ID := .I]
> dt[((a == T & b >= 4) | (a == F & b <= 2))
+    , .(ID, a, b, agg_id = rleid(cumsum(c(0,diff(ID) - 1))))]
    ID     a  b agg_id
 1:  3 FALSE  1      1
 2:  5 FALSE  2      2
 3:  6  TRUE 15      2
 4:  7 FALSE  1      2
 5:  8  TRUE 20      2
 6:  9 FALSE  2      2
 7: 10  TRUE 10      2
 8: 12  TRUE 50      3
 9: 13 FALSE  1      3
10: 14  TRUE 20      3
```

That's why I have an `ifelse(.N>1 ,...)` statement as well as a `dt[e==1 | ..., e:=0]` statement.

The last item of note is that in order to aggregate it, there needed to be a unique ID. All of the rows that did not meet the previous criteria had no `agg_ID`. So this code accounts for that:

```
dt[is.na(agg_ID), agg_ID := .I + max(dt[['agg_ID']], na.rm = T) ]
```